# find $\lim_{n→∞}x_n$?..

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given that the function

$f(x) = \frac {x^3 +1}{3}$ has three fixed points $ α, β, γ $ in $(−2, −1)$, $(0, 1)$ and$ (1, 2)$ respectively, let us define a
sequence of real numbers {$x_n$} as
$x_1 = γ − 0.01$ , $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$,$ n = 1, 2, 3, . .$

Given that the sequence converges, find 
$\lim_{n→∞}x_n$?

My solution :  Here $\{x_n\}$ is monotone,  so  it converges to a finite $L$

Now if $x_n→L$ then $f(x_n)→f(L)$ because f is continuous but $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$. Hence $f(L)=L$.

Now $\lim_{n→∞}x_n =\lim_{n→∞}f(L)$,

$f(L) = \frac {L^3 +1} {3}$

$L^3 +1 = 3L$,

$L(L^2-3) = 1 .-1$, that is $L= 1$ and $L^2 -3 = -1$.

ANSWER :   $\lim_{n→∞}x_n=L =1$ or $\lim_{n→∞}x_n=L = \sqrt2$.

I'm  confused  that  I'm getting  two  values  of $\lim_{n→∞}x_n$.

Now  My  question  is that  what  is the correct value of $\lim_{n→∞}x_n$ ????

Comment: I don't understand how you would get the fixed points you mentioned. I would solve them from the equation
$$
\frac{x^3 +1 }{3} = x
$$
This gives three solutions: $x\approx -1.1879$, $x\approx 0.347$ and $x \approx 1.1532$. In practice, if you choose $x$ between $x\approx -1.1879$ and $x \approx 1.1532$, and repeatedly apply $f$, you converge into $x \approx 0.34730$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get these values for the solutions of the equation $f(x)=x$? None of them is correct. What you were supposed to prove was that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=\gamma$. Since the sequence is increasing and $\alpha<\beta<x_1<\gamma$, the limit can only be $\gamma$. In fact, since $x_1\leqslant x_2\leqslant x_3\leqslant\cdots$, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ cannot be $\alpha$ or $\beta$. Since the limit exists, it can only be $\gamma$.

Comment: From the  question $f(x)  = x_{n+1} $ so $f(x) = x$ ..But im not getting How u directly show  that ,$ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n =\gamma$??? can u little more elaborate ...

Comment: @Henry I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: thanks a lots @Jose carlos santos

Comment: It's not the case that $\{x_n\}$ is increasing.