# which user answer is correct ?.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

It is given that the function $f(x) = \frac{x^3 + 1}{3}$ has three fixed points $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$ in $(-2,-1), (0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$ respectively. A sequence of real numbers is defined as $$x_1 =\gamma - 0.01\qquad , \qquad x_{n+1} = f(x_n) \enspace\forall n = 1, 2, 3,\cdots.$$ Given that the sequence converges, find 
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$.

My attempt :  I have  found the  two answer , Im confused that  which one  correct ?

## first anwser by jose carlos sir [image]

## $2$nd answer  by Muhammad sir

[image]

Link to first: [find $\lim_{n→∞}x_n$?..](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762982/find-lim-n)→∞x-n

Link to second: [Convergence of sequence involving fixed points of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983821/convergence-of-sequence-involving-fixed-points-of-a-function)

Here, I'm confused  that  which  answer is correct ?

Comment: Could you link the question?

Comment: $2$nd answer link @cmk https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983821/convergence-of-sequence-involving-fixed-points-of-a-function

Comment: first answer link @cmk https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762982/find-lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9ex-n

Comment: Muhammad's solution matches your situation better. The limit is indeed $\beta$

Comment: Jose Carlos Santos is incorrect that the sequence is increasing.

Comment: The intervals containing the fixed points are correct. The value $\gamma - 0.01$ lies in the interval $(1,2),$ where is the sequence decreasing. As the sequence is supposed to be convergent, the limit is the fixed point $\beta.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a discrete version of the derivative, namely $x_{n+1}-x_n$, to talk about the dynamics of this system. The fixed points are equilibria of the system, that is to say that their discrete "derivative" vanishes. So once you are at a fixed point, your value doesn't change anymore.

Since $\gamma-0.01\in(\beta,\gamma)$ let's take a look at the values of the "derivative" on that interval (the "derivative" is only $0$ at the fixed points, so intermediate value theorem tells us it must have a definite sign between them). The only number we know for sure we can test that is between the two points is $1$. Plugging in,

$$\frac{1^3+1}{3}-1 = -\frac{1}{3} < 0$$

so the sequence is always decreasing for values on that interval. But do the values on the interval stay within that interval? How do we know that it will continue sliding down to $\beta$ instead of, say, hopping over to $-1$?

We can note that $\frac{x^3+1}{3}$ is a monotonically increasing function, which means that $a\leq b \implies f(a)\leq f(b)$. Using this we can deduce that for any $x_n\in(\beta,\gamma)$:

$$\beta \leq x_n \leq \gamma \implies f(\beta) \leq f(x_n) \leq f(\gamma) \implies \beta \leq x_{n+1} \leq \gamma$$

because $\beta$ and $\gamma$ were fixed points of $f$. Therefore we have proved that the sequence is always decreasing and always confined to the interval $(\beta,\gamma)$, so the limit has to be $\beta$.

(One can prove by contradiction that the sequence cannot stop "before" it reaches $\beta$, since the sequence must still decrease for $\beta+\epsilon$).

Comment: why u direct plug  $1 $  why not  any other number  ?

Comment: @jasmine I think I found the source of your confusion. $\beta \in (0,1)$ and $\gamma \in (1,2)$, so what is the only number we can guarantee has to be between them?

Comment: 1  ohhh got its   ..thanks  u @ Ninad Munshi

Answer (score 3):

You can answer experimentally. By solving the cubic, $\gamma-0.01\approx 1.522088886238$ and the next iterates are

$$1.4781786918566,\\1.4099461806973,\\1.2676333392617,\\1.0123175885187,\\0.6791366011261,\\0.4377452710573,\\0.3490536023807,\\0.347509379493,\\0.3473220649546,\\\cdots$$

We have $\beta\approx0.3473220649546$.

This is not a formal proof as finite arithmetic might trick us, but the chances are very very low.